# SIMULINK Holding Previous Value of a Signal

Tags: c, configuration, state, simulink

I am trying to implement a pulse generator in SIMULINK that needs to know the previous 2 input values i.e. I need to know the previous 2 state values for the input signal. Also, I need to know the previous output value.

My pseudo code is:

```
IF !input AND  input_prevValue AND !input_prevValue2
    output = !output_pv
ELSE
    output = output_pv;
```

I know that I can use legacy function importer and use C code to do this job in SIMULINK. However, the problem arises when you apply a configuration reference set to your model. The key problem is the flexibility. When you use this model somewhere else (say share it with a colleague or whoever), unless you have used a configuration reference set, you can rebuild the code (i.e. from S-Function Block) and run your model. But you cannot rebuild the code if the configuration reference set is applied.

My solution would be to implement the logic in a way that I can do the same without C functions. I tried to use the memory block in SIMULINK but apparently it doesn't do it. Does anyone know how to hold previous values for input and output in SIMULINK (for as long as the model is open)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with a [MATLAB Function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block? Alternatively, if you have a Stateflow license, this would lend itself nicely to a state chart.

**EDIT**

Based on your pseudo-code, I would expect the code in the MATLAB Function block to look like this

```
function op = logic_fcn(ip,ip_prev,ip_prev2,op_prev)
% #codegen

if ~ip && ip_prev && ~ip_prev2
   op = ~op_prev;
else
   op = op_prev;
end
```

where `ip`, `ip_prev`, `ip_prev2` and `op_prev` are defined as boolean inputs and `op` as a boolean output. If you are using a fixed-step discrete solver, the memory block should work so that you would for example feed the output of the MATLAB Function block to a memory block (with the correct sample time), and the output of the memory block to the `op_prev` input of the MATLAB Function block.

You could (and should) test your function in MATLAB first (and/or a test Simulink model) to make sure it works and produces the output you expect for a given input.

Comment: using MATLAB FUNCTION block? I tried buy supplying output from memory blocks as previous values, but didn't work :(

Comment: also I cannot use Stateflow...no license

Comment: Frighteningly, my function looked exactly like  yours, I used a fixed step discrete solver with a step-size of 0.033 (that is my scheduler rate anyway). However, I always see my output as 0 :(

But I will try again and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

This is reasonably straight forward to do with fundamental blocks,

[image]

Note that for the Switch block the "Criteria for passing first input:" has been changed to "u2~=0".